# Set text in a textView

Tags: android, textview

I have a second activity that query an online database and I want to set text of the TextView but I can't.

This is code of second activity:

```
public class sendQuery extends main  {
/////////// Public method to send Query ///////////
public static String send(String query, Activity sendQuery) {
    String result = "0";
    InputStream is = null;
    String weekDayVal=null;
    String provola=null;
    //the query to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> querySend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    querySend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("querySend",query));

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://locali.altervista.org/php/locali.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(querySend));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        try{
            JSONArray weekDetails = new JSONArray ( result); // Your response string
            for(int index=0;index < 1/*weekDetails.length()*/;index++)
            {
            JSONObject tempWeekDetail = weekDetails.getJSONObject(index);
            weekDayVal = tempWeekDetail.getString("Lunedi");// Value for Monday
            //added this Log which you can view from LogCat. also changed above variable name
            Log.i("Resp Value","Moday Value "+weekDayVal);
            JSONObject provino = weekDetails.getJSONObject(index);
            provola = provino.getString("Martedi");// Value for Monday
            //added this Log which you can view from LogCat. also changed above variable name
            Log.i("Resp Value","Moday Value "+provola);
            }
            TextView text = (TextView) sendQuery.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
            text.setText(provola);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {


            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result: "+e.toString());
    }

    Log.i("SendQUERY", result);
    return result;
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong? I don't understand.
Thanks.

This is main activity:

```
 public class main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView resLayout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);


    String res = sendQuery.send("SELECT * FROM contatti", null);

    resLayout.append(res);



}
}
```

Comment: `but I can't`... what is the problem you are facing here? did logcat saying anything? It seems like you are setting text to `TextView` in a non UI Thread...

Comment: can you show the error log?

Comment: there are no errors, I do not see the text in the TextView

Comment: As someone pointed out, probably because it's only in a `catch` block. However, as Gopal pointed out, it also looks like you are doing it in a background `Thread` which will give errors even if you do catch an exception.

Comment: I tried to move everything in the "try" but it does not work the same

Comment: In the line where you have 

    TextView text = (TextView) sendQuery.findViewById(R.id.textView10);

change it to,

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

I'm not sure why you had the sendQuery there - did it throw an error without that? findViewById() is a non static method which in your case is being called from a static method. Can you change modifier of send?

Comment: it appears to me that error, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the TextView in a catch block - this catch block will only be executed if the try block throws an exception. Since the try block works fine in your case, this catch block is never executed. Set the TextView in the corresponding try block and everything will work fine.

Edit: Make your code like the following:

```
try{
        TextView text = (TextView) sendQuery.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        JSONArray weekDetails = new JSONArray ( result); // Your response string
        for(int index=0;index < 1/*weekDetails.length()*/;index++)
        {
        JSONObject tempWeekDetail = weekDetails.getJSONObject(index);
        weekDayVal = tempWeekDetail.getString("Lunedi");// Value for Monday
        //added this Log which you can view from LogCat. also changed above variable name
        Log.i("Resp Value","Moday Value "+weekDayVal);
        JSONObject provino = weekDetails.getJSONObject(index);
        provola = provino.getString("Martedi");// Value for Monday
        //added this Log which you can view from LogCat. also changed above variable name
        Log.i("Resp Value","Moday Value "+provola);
        text.setText(provola);
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the updated code where you have made these changes?

Comment: This is because of java's scope resolution - provola cannot be seen outside the block where it is being declared (a block in java is anything that is enclosed by the {} braces). Use the setText() within the same scope where provola is being set and it should work. You can see it in the logs because your log statement printing this out is within the block. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: also in this way does not work, it does not set the text of the TextView.

Comment: Can you see the value of provola in the logs? If yes, the only thing I can think of is that this is being run from a background thread. I can see this class extending from another class. Is main an activity or a fragment?

Comment: If you can provide a dump of your code somewhere and provide me a link to it, I can go over it.

Comment: Yes i can see  the value of provola. Do you want see main activity?

Comment: Yes, I can't see anything wrong in this but I think you are somehow not getting your sendQuery - it is not getting set up the way it is expected to.

Answer (score 0):

What i think the problem might be you are setting the value of textview without waiting for the query to return a response. Because of which you might not be able to set correct value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , as mentioned above, you are setting the text of the TextView in a catch block, which is wrong for many reasons.
Second,  define your textview and add it on a fatherLayout out of the catch block with GONE or INVISIBLE visibility , and set the text of it in your catch block and change the visibility to VISIBLE.

Also, all this stuff must be done after your request is finished.